# Javascript variable env convert to int variable

Tags: javascript

I wouldike to know how can I convert variable from my env file :

.env :

```
ID=10
```

.js :

```
export const injectedConnector = new InjectedConnector({
  supportedChainIds: [1, process.env["ID"];],
});
```

Comment: `parseInt(process.env["ID"], 10)`

Comment: @Emanuele I try it but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you elaborate on what does not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by one of the following methods

```
1) parseInt(process.env.ID, 10);
2) Number(process.env.ID);
3) +process.env.ID;
```